question from applied multivariate data analysis
The airquality dataset in R provides information on air quality measurements in New York City. Each row represents a day, and each column represents a different measurement related to air quality.
Columns in airquality:
Ozone: Ozone concentration (ppb)
Solar.R: Solar radiation (langley)
Wind: Wind speed (mph)
Temp: Temperature (degrees Fahrenheit)
Month: Month of the year (1-12)
Day: Day of the month (1-31)
Questions:

Load the built-in R dataset airquality. Inspect the summary statistics of the dataset along with the covariance and correlation matrix.(8 marks)

Visualize the data to understand the distribution and relationships of air quality measurements. (4 marks)


